# Accessibility: Registered Trademark logo in Text Logo custom font face

Tags: accessibility, font, type

I have created a custom font face for a client's logo, which is a registered trademark. For SEO reasons, the Logo is in a H1 tag at the top of the page. From an accessibility perspective, would it be acceptable to drop the '®' from the type and put the registered trademark logo in with another glyph? I.e. changing the S glyph to contain the registered trademark logo? [image: Cook's Pantry Logo]

Comment: Looks like the (R) is in the wrong place - unless your client somehow registered the word `COOK'S`.

Comment: Danny, as stated previously, I could put the registered trademark on the y as well, but that isn’t what this question is about. Is the knowledge that the stylized text in a particular font face is a logo and a registered trademark important to people using screen readers? Take any other brand name in a stylized font as text and I’m sure you could see how placement may become problematic. Schwinn, gerber, omega brewing, et al. The placement of the R has no legal requirement per the USPTO, I think the placement was intended to ensure Cook’s & Cook’s Pantry we’e recognized on one application.

Answer (score 1):

Is the client dead set for having the registered mark on the logo? There's a lot of brands that don't place it there at all. I feel it adds clutter to the logo personally and looks a lot cleaner without it.

If the client is persistent about letting the world know it exists, I'm not sure what advantages you gain by changing it to a glyph. Screen readers can read the ® as registered mark. I think you would lose that by trying to do a custom icon.

If you do place it on the logo, I'd make sure to add it after the full trademark. Current placement looks as though there's a trademark on the term Cook's.

Comment: Aesthetics of the logo aside, I think the advantage may be in SEO. People will search for “cook’s pantry” not “cook’s&reg; pantry”. By adding the registered mark to the “s” glyph, screen readers lose the ability to describe the text as a registered trademark logo. From an accessibility standpoint, is this acceptable, seeing as the trade dress of a brand is unlikely to be relevant information to those using assistive technology?

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question about the glyph but since the trademark is on Cook's Pantry it should be at the end of the big header text anyways and you could utilize a div tag with custom class and css outside of the H1 to place the registered mark on the logo.

Hopefully someone else here can provide more insight into the question about customizing the S glyph. Sorry I wasn't able to help on that.

Comment: Mat, I could place an image in the middle of the logo where the current trademark logo is, or at the end of “cook’s pantry”, but tying the alt tag of that image to the stylized text in the H1 tag, I don’t see how to do that in a coherent way. span with a name and aria described by possibly? This is more about what information should be accessible than where the registered trademark logo should go. My custom font face could support putting it on the “y” glyph in this scenario. Is the trade dress of a logo useful information to those using assistive technologies?